# MariaDB local access error (remote access fine)

Tags: php, mariadb

It seems most access issues have been remote, but this is the reverse problem.
Here are all the error messages:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.168.101.35 (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/hamlookup/index.php on line 291
PHP Warning:  main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /var/www/html/hamlookup/index.php on line 291
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_fields() in /var/www/html/hamlookup/index.php on line 295
```

I have setup MariaDB on CentOS 7 with password and I can remotely access it from various Windows machines using any SQL client (php or apache not involved).

I can also access it using the mysql command line tool.
mysqli is enabled in php (I checked with phpinfo()).

However, I get these errors when I check my web page running "php index.php" at the console, and of course when the web page is accessed via apache it crashes there too.

The lines causing the error are (line numbers in square brackets):

```
[290]  $mysqli = new mysqli( "10.168.101.35","root","*****","hamlookup" );
[291]  if( $mysqli->error ){
[292]    [calling error function here then exit]
[293]  }
[294]  $result = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
[295]  $fieldinfo = $mysqli->fetch_fields( $result );
```

It seems like it's an issue between php, mysql and apache but I can't figure it out.

I have also tried to connect via PDO and I still cannot connect to the server.

This is ridiculous since I can connect via CLI and via the network, simply php is not able to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

you need add the line in file /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld] 
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

restart mysql

Comment: That did not work. I also tried bind-address 0.0.0.0 (no = sign), bind-address 10.168.101.35 (the server's IP address) and bind-address 127.0.0.1, all with or without = sign and none worked. Looking at the mariadb log, it seems like the server is always creating a socket on 0.0.0.0, regardless of the bind-address in the configuration file.

Comment: I also went into mysql CLI and added this: GRANT ALL ON hamlookup.* TO 'root'@'10.168.101.35'; restarted mysql and it also made no difference

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...

I was checking $myDPO->errorInfo() to verify success incorrectly.

This was migrated from the old mysql_*** access API and it turns out that in fact I was accessing the database.

Once the errorInfo() check was changed, it seems like everything is working.

Sorry for the bandwidth.